# How to increase the temperature when CPU scaling is triggered?

Tags: cpu, overheating, temperature

I notice that when running a stress test in Ubuntu desktop, my laptop begins the throttle when temperatures reach ~90C. I have noticed that when Ubuntu-server was installed on the same laptop, throttling began at much higher temperatures. Only at about 100C. I was not able to recreate this in Ubuntu-desktop. How can I change the temperature at which throttling begins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that stopping the service thermald makes it possible for the system to reach much higher temperatures before throttling.